# Exclude lambda (or delegates) in DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

I have a scenario where I will receive a dictionary<string, object>();
that can also be recursive though not always, but the main issue is that it contains lambdas.

as we implement a transaction system I need to clone it, which works fine until I hit the lambdas.
I tried to move these to delegates but the error changes and still gives me runtime issue.

technically I can re inject the lambdas after the cloning, but don't know how to tell the DataContractSerializer to ignore these.

I also cannot remove the lambdas prior to the cloning as the original object still needs them if I cancel the transaction.

Comment: You using [tag:.net] or actually [tag:.net-core]?  Also, do you want to clone the delegates, or preserve them as-is?  (Actually, I can't really imagine how to clone a delegate including any captured variables.)

Comment: good point using .net framework 4.8. I dont need to clone the delegates as I can re inject them, I just dont want to remove them from the original. my current idea would be to clone the dictionaries individually, swap them, clone the object and then put them back in the original object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Clone()` method you can use the [data contract surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates) functionality to replace all `System.Delegate` objects in your serialization graph with a serializable type, such as a lookup in a dictionary of delegates that you build as you serialize.  Then, as you deserialize, you could replace the deserialized serialization surrogates with the original delegates.

The following does this:

```
public static class DataContractExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> Clone(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            return null;

        var surrogate = new DelegateSurrogateSelector();

        var types = new[] 
            {
                typeof(Dictionary<string, object>),
                typeof(DelegateSurrogateId),
                // Add in whatever additional known types you want.
            };

        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(
            typeof(Dictionary<string, object>),
            types, int.MaxValue, false, false,
            surrogate);

        var xml = dictionary.ToContractXml(serializer, null);

        return FromContractXml<Dictionary<string, object>>(xml, serializer);
    }

    public static string ToContractXml<T>(this T obj, DataContractSerializer serializer, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(obj == null ? typeof(T) : obj.GetType());
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T FromContractXml<T>(string xml, DataContractSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml ?? ""))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        {
            return (T)(serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T))).ReadObject(xmlReader);
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    class DelegateSurrogateId
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class DelegateSurrogateSelector : IDataContractSurrogate
    {
        public Dictionary<int, System.Delegate> DelegateDictionary { get; private set; }

        public DelegateSurrogateSelector()
        {
            this.DelegateDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Delegate>();
        }

        #region IDataContractSurrogate Members

        public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
        {
            if (typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                return typeof(DelegateSurrogateId);
            return type;
        }

        public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
        {
            var id = obj as DelegateSurrogateId;
            if (id != null)
                return DelegateDictionary[id.Id];
            return obj;
        }

        public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
        {
            var del = obj as Delegate;
            if (del != null)
            {
                var id = DelegateDictionary.Count;
                DelegateDictionary.Add(id, del);
                return new DelegateSurrogateId { Id = id };
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Using the above `Clone()` extension method, the following test will pass:

```
Func<bool> returnTrue = () => true;
Func<bool> returnFalse = () => false;

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "a", "hello"},
    { "b", 10101 },
    { "c", returnTrue },
    { "d", new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "q", 101 },
            { "r", returnFalse },
        }
    }
};

var dictionary2 = dictionary.Clone();

Assert.AreEqual(returnTrue, dictionary2["c"]); // No failure
var inner = (Dictionary<string, object>)dictionary["d"];
var inner2 = (Dictionary<string, object>)dictionary2["d"];

Assert.AreEqual(inner["r"], inner2["r"]);    // No failure
```

Notes:

- Data contract serialization surrogates work differently in .NET Core.  There, the [`IDataContractSurrogate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate?view=netframework-4.8) interface has been replaced with [`ISerializationSurrogateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogateprovider?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about surrogates and the docs from the datacontractserializer do not mention it! did not think to search in extensions. a bit heavier than I was hoping for, it would truly be nice if there was an ignoretype similar to knowntype, but this is great for what I need

Comment: correction it was indeed in the docs, I just dont know how to read or was not looking for the right keywords!